# Correct way to get model list in another model

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am working on a spring mvc app in which there are 2 entities, contact and location. Following are my contact and location models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class ContactModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="contactid")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int contactId;

    @Column(name="contactname")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name="contactemail")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="contactphone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name="locationid")
    private int locationId;
}
```

Location model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Location")
public class LocationModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="locationid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private int locationId;

    @Column(name="locationname")
    private String locationName;

    @Column(name="locationdesc")
    private String locationDescription;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String locationType;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="district")
    private String district;

    @Column(name="lattitude")
    private String lattitude;

    @Column(name="longitude")
    private String longitude;
}
```

In contact dao, I am getting contact list using below code:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ContactModel.class);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("contactName"));
return criteria.list();
```

Now I need to show contact list on contact home page which will show contact name and its corresponding location name.

To show the contact list, I need to create join in contact and location tables. Is this the proper way? How can we do this in hibernate?

Also is it the proper way to add location entity in contact entity, or do I have to use location model in contact?

Comment: you have relate both entity with relation

Answer (score 1):

You have to relate your both entities with relation .I am assuming that ContactModel have One-To-One relation with LocationModel

Change your ContactModel to

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class ContactModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="contactid")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int contactId;

    @Column(name="contactname")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name="contactemail")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="contactphone")
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne
    @Column(name="locationid")
    private LocationModel location;
}
```

and do the rest of thing same as you are doing select only the ContactModel List objects.

```
public List<ContactModel> allContactModel(){  
          Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          Criteria criteria =  session.createCriteria(ContactModel.class);
          criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("contactName"));
          return criteria.list();
}
```

and get the value of location in your controller by iterating over list ContactModel and fetch the LocationModel object from ContactModel as you fetch normal variable by ClassName.Fieldname.Here It will Give you a LocationModel object

```
List<ContactModel> mylist=ContactModel.allContactModel();
for(ContactModel cm: mylist){
   LocationModel lm=ContactModel.getLocationModel();
   System.out.println(cm.getContactName+" location is "+lm.getLocationName);
}
```

Now you have the LocationModel, you can fetch its further values also.

You can also further enhance this onetoone relation by specifying fetchtype,cascadetype etc accoding to your requirements.
Note:Assuming that you are have getter and setter in your model

Answer (score 0):

i think the right way is that the contact can have a location, now add a location object to your contact, something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class ContactModel {

    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "locationid", nullable = false)
    private LocationModel location;

    // can be removed
    @Column(name="locationid")
    private int locationId;
    ...

}
```

if you have this you get the location object when you call a contact record